# Is there a syntax error in this Bash function? Functionality works fine when hardcoded into main loop

Tags: linux, bash

I have a function that assigns an element of `workspace[i]` to a corrosponding "tag." For example, if `workspace[3]` has the name "firefox," it will underline the name "firefox," and if not, there will be no underline. Outside of the function, and inside the main `while` loop, this works perfectly, as such:

```
# dummy assignment for workspace_raw[i]
workspace_raw[1]=firefox

# code without function
boolean_check=false

for (( i=0 ; i <= 15 ; i++ ))
do
    workspaces[i]="${workspace_raw[i]}"
    if [ "${workspaces[i]}" == "firefox" ] 
    then
        boolean_check=true
    else
        false 
    fi
done

if $boolean_check
then
    workspace_firefox="\u3firefox\u0"
else
    workspace_firefox="\u0firefox\u0"
fi
```

However, putting the functionality inside of a function and calling it with an argument does absolutely nothing, but doesn't display an error either. This is the code I'm using with the function, and it doesn't work:

```
# dummy assignment for $workspace_raw[i]
workspace_raw[1]=firefox

# assign name for function argument
tag_name1=firefox

# the function
assign_workspace()
{
tag=$1
boolean_check=false

for (( i=0 ; i <= 15 ; i++ ))
do
    workspaces[i]="${workspace_raw[i]}"

    if [ "${workspaces[i]}" == "$tag" ] 
    then
        boolean_check=true
    else
        false 
    fi
done

if $boolean_check
then
     declare workspace_$tag="\u3test$tag\u0"
else
     declare workspace_$tag="\u0test$tag\u0"
fi
}

# call function with argument
assign_workspace $tag_name1
```

No idea what to do. Since the function's code works when hardcoded into the main loop, I feel like I'm making a syntax error somewhere in the code.  Here is the entire script if necessary:
http://pastebin.com/39WmPUvi

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`declare` inside a function, by default, will create a local variable. If you want the `workspace_$tag` variables available outside that function, use the `-g` flag.

```
if $boolean_check
then
     declare -g workspace_$tag="\u3test$tag\u0"
else
     declare -g workspace_$tag="\u0test$tag\u0"
fi
```